# Hatoras Nedarim for wife taking her husband's Minhagim

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage, nedarim-shevuot

According to Minchas Yaakov 112:2 and [Darchei Teshuva 112:94](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41145&st=&pgnum=14), one who is always careful with Pas Yisrael and now wants to start eating Pas Paltar would have to be Matir Neder. Suppose a girl who was always careful to eat Pas Yisrael is now marrying a guy who eats Pas Paltar, would she still have to be Matir Neder or, since she is changing her status by marriage, is it not necessary?

This question is applicable by any case where the wife maintains a Chumra which the husband does not. The above is an example.

Comment: I have never heard of women doing hatarat nedarim if their new husband waits less time than they do after meat.

Comment: @DoubleAA: Neither did I. However in Shul this morning a fellow insisted that a Rav told his wife to do so for Cholov Stam when she married him. I am trying to find out who says so and where.

Answer (score 6):

Halichos Shlomo 1 1:7 says that a lady who gets married to someone who holds that it is required to wait 3 hours after eating meat before eating dairy, and until now she always held 6 hours, may change her Minhag to her husbands and is not required to do Hataras Nedarim.