# Getting Married With Different Customs

Tags: kashrut-kosher, marriage, meat-and-milk

B'H I'm getting married in a few months and my fiancée waits 3 hours between meat and milk and I wait 6.

In general, does a wife take on all the customs of her husband? In my example, would she have to take on the custom of waiting 6 hours too? Or can she maintain her custom and wait 3 hours between meat and milk?

Comment: Hi Doronsky85. Mazel Tov! You two should speak with your rabbi for a final ruling and not rely on what you read here. We are not a rabbi and are not qualified to give you a ruling, only to provide some ideas and sources that help you understand what's going on. All the best!

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28144/759

Comment: I took the liberty of de-personalizing your question. In the future, we prefer them that way to make it clear that we are not offering personal halachic guidance. Mazal tov!

Answer (score 8):

Rav Moshe Feinstein ([Igros Moshe 1:158](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=916&st=&pgnum=277)) rules that the wife takes the customs of the husband whether they are more lenient or more strict:

> האשה צריכה להתנהג כמנהג הבעל בין לחומרא בין לקולא

This is the same as with anyone that moves to a different place and plans to stay there, that he keeps the customs of that place ([Shulchan Aruch YD 214:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.214.2?with=all)).

I forgot to send you MAZAL TOV MAZAL TOV