# Marriage between followers of different Hasidic courts

Tags: marriage, chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

I know that high-profile marriages between followers of different Hasidic courts occur -- such as the Belzer Rebbe, Rabbi Yissachar Dov Rokach and one of the Satmar Rebbes, Rabbi Aharon Teitelbaum each marrying a daughter of Rabbi Moshe Yehoshua Hager, the Vizhnitz Rebbe.

My questions is:  When this does happen is there a general rule that has been published by Hasidic Rebbes/Ravs that the woman follows the Hasidic traditions of her husband's Hasidic court?

Comment: Like mbloch mentioned, your first question seems to be a "Jews not Judaism" one. Regarding your second question, it seems like a duplicate of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70523/getting-married-with-different-customs

Comment: @Salmononius2 do Hasidic Jews follow the rulings of R' Moshe Feinstein?  Is there an answer relating to Hasidic minhagim that has been answered with sources from a Hasidic Rebbe or Rav?

Comment: I agree this seems like a duplicate. If you want chasidic answers specifically there you can offer a bounty.

Comment: @DonielF it did not answer my question at all because the sources cited are not necessarily followed by the followers of Hasidic courts.

Comment: @Mordechai Duplicates are judged based on the questions themselves, not the answers to each question. As DoubleAA commented earlier, you can post a bounty on that other question if you want different responses.

Comment: @DonielF my question asks for something "published by Hasidic Rebbes/Ravs".  I would not consider it a duplicate.  The question is eligible for a bounty tomorrow. I know we have Hasidic Jews who post here from time to time and would love to hear their answers.

Comment: @Mordechai https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3507/ is the relevant post for site policy of duplicates. Wouldn't you agree that a complete answer to "does a woman take on her husband's minhagim" should address "does a woman take on her husband's minhagim if they're of different forms of chassidus", even if the current answers don't?

Comment: No, I don't think it does. Depending on which Hasidic court you follow you may or may not carry on Shabbos in various parts of Brooklyn for example. My question may have a lot of overlap with the other question but I believe it is different. I don't think the community needs to have an obsessive view towards closing questions over some overlap with other questions it doesn't seem like the best way for it to grow.  I am hoping a Hasidic Jew is able to give some thoughts on this issue for me, please leave it open so I can see.The other question does not seem like the best place to get my answer.